# Storing messages in MongoDB from a chat

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am a student building a project for a made up law firm, and I am trying to figure out the best way to use mongoDB/mongoose to store all the chat messages between the attorney and the customer in the backend.  This is my current schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },
  customer: Object,
  attorney: Object,
  log: [
    {
      by: String,
      sent: Date,
      message: String,
    },
  ],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  UpdatedAt: Date,
});

const Chat = mongoose.model("chats", chatSchema);

module.exports = Chat;
```

What would be the best way to implement this so I could easily access the messages in the front end, and be able to have a new chat created between the same 2 people or 2 different people, and their messages be correctly be assigned to them?

I tried creating a schema for the chat, and so far I've been able to save a new chat to my collections.  Where I'm confused at is how to make sure messages are saved in this collection, and that each message and message sender are saved together.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate schema `userSchema` for client & attorney, and reference them in the `chatSchema`.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  category: String, // client/attorney
  // add more fields if you want to
});

const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },
  customer: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  attorney: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  log: [
    {
      by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      sent: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      message: String,
    }
  ],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: Date,
});

const Chat = mongoose.model("Chat", chatSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```